# how to send messages to different instances of my application over the local network with iOS

Tags: ios, communication

I would like my application to send a message to another instance of the same application. This another instance would run (obviously) on a different device. Both device (sender and receiver) are connected to the same local network (which may or may not be connected to the Internet).
I would prefer a server-free solution (i.e. point-to-point) if possible  i.e. with only the mobile devices involved.

What API/framework do you recommend to do this ? (Apple iOS SDK, open source ...)

Thanks !

Comment: when I say 'message' I mean just a character string (it has nothing to do with iMessage/SMS etc....)

Comment: Check out the MultiPeer framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely [Multipeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html)

Comment: well, after having a look at your link, it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for ! :-) Thank you so much JordanC (and Sirens) !